# Как принять данные от ajax serializeArray в php?

Tags: php, javascript

[Фото var_dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4afSj.png)
Доброго времени суток , как принять ?

```
                        var str = $("form").serialize();
                        var data=JSON.stringify(str)
                        $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType:'json',
                        url: "system/editProduct.php",
                        cache: false,
                        data: {data},
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log(data);
                        }
```

Answer (score 1):

В первую очередь всегда смотрите, что именно и в каком формате всё это передаётся(в DevTools, например).

Если тело запроса корректно сериализовано, и, желательно, присутствует корректный content-type, переходите к серверной стороне.

Для `application/x-www-formurlencoded` php сам парсит тело запроса. Результат парсинга попадает в суперглобальный массив `$_POST`.

Любой другой формат(`application/json`, например) придётся парсить самостоятельно:

1. Получаете сырое тело запроса: `$rawBody = file_get_contents('php://input')`
2. Десериализуете: `$data = json_decode($rawBody, true);`

Answer (score 0):

Передавая данные где либо по `AJAX`, советую использовать `JSON`, потому что это де-факто стандарт передачи данных в большинстве `API`, и просто потому что с ним удобно работать.

В `JS` Для работы с `JSON` Есть методы `JSON.parse(string); JSON.stringify(object);`

в `PHP` функции

`json_encode(string, int); 
json_encode(object);`

Comment: `var str = $("form").serialize();
                    var data=JSON.stringify(str)
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType:'json',
                        url: "system/editProduct.php",
                        cache: false,
                        data: {data},
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log(data);
                        },`   Типа этого?

Comment: Нет, вы используете внутреннюю сериализация, вы сразу после использования метода `.serialize` Можете сразу отправлять данные на сервер, они прийдет в массиве `$_POST` Парой ключ-значение где ключи это имена полей в форме.